# R - check if it is true: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, shiny

Why do I get this error message:

```
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I want to check if it is true then do something. This works OK on my RStudio but I get the error above when the code is on the production server:

```
na <- all(is.na(Df[, columnName]))
if (isTRUE(na)) {
   # do something
}
```

It is the same for:

```
if (na == TRUE) {
```

Any idea why??

**EDIT:**

It seems that it is `all(is.na(Df[, columnName]))` that is causing this error.

My Shiny on my production server is on an older version - **0.12.1**. While my local machine is on **1.0.3.** How can I verify whether it is the problem of the Shiny versions?

Below are my data samples.

This data has **no error**:

```
structure(list(site = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = "LW2", class = "factor"), code = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "LW2", class = "factor"), 
    date = structure(c(1493251200, 1493254800, 1493258400, 1493262000, 
    1493265600, 1493269200, 1493272800, 1493276400, 1493280000, 
    1493283600, 1493287200, 1493290800, 1493294400, 1493298000, 
    1493301600, 1493305200, 1493308800, 1493312400, 1493316000, 
    1493319600, 1493323200, 1493326800, 1493330400, 1493334000
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), PM25 = c(4.4, 
    4.3, 5.3, 2.1, 4.3, 16.1, 21.1, 22.7, 27.8, 22.2, 11.3, 13.4, 
    14.2, 13.8, 15.9, 17.6, 18.5, 24.7, 23, 31.6, 18.9, 23, 11.7, 
    11.7)), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("site", "code", "date", 
"PM25"), vars = list(site, code), drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    0:23), group_sizes = 24L, biggest_group_size = 24L, labels = structure(list(
    site = structure(1L, .Label = "LW2", class = "factor"), code = structure(1L, .Label = "LW2", class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = "data.frame", vars = list(site, code), drop = TRUE, .Names = c("site", 
"code")))
```

This data gives the **error** above:

```
structure(list(site = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = "HK6", class = "factor"), code = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "HK6", class = "factor"), 
    date = structure(c(1493251200, 1493254800, 1493258400, 1493262000, 
    1493265600, 1493269200, 1493272800, 1493276400, 1493280000, 
    1493283600, 1493287200, 1493290800, 1493294400, 1493298000, 
    1493301600, 1493305200, 1493308800, 1493312400, 1493316000, 
    1493319600, 1493323200, 1493326800, 1493330400, 1493334000
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), PM25 = c(NaN, 
    NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
    NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN)), row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("site", 
"code", "date", "PM25"), vars = list(site, code), drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    0:23), group_sizes = 24L, biggest_group_size = 24L, labels = structure(list(
    site = structure(1L, .Label = "HK6", class = "factor"), code = structure(1L, .Label = "HK6", class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = "data.frame", vars = list(site, code), drop = TRUE, .Names = c("site", 
"code")))
```

I am checking the column name of `PM25`.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. Typically that error appears when the condition in the `if` statement is `NA`. If you try `if (NA) print(4)` you'll see the same error.

Comment: Note that `if(na == TRUE)` is an exact equivalent of `if(na)`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas thanks. I have tried that too and getting the same error.

Comment: @nicola I added the data samples. please see my edit above. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The statement within the if condition might be giving `NA`. You can avoid that using:

```
if (all(is.na(Df[, columnName]))) {
   # do something
}
```

I am not sure of your exact context, but you can try this.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have tried that. it seems that it is `all(is.na(Df[, columnName]))` that is causing this error. My Shiny on my production server might be on an older version. How can I verify whether it is the problem of the Shiny version?

Comment: I do not see if it is due to the change in Shiny versions. I will get back to you once I have some idea about it.